# Set OnClick Listener on multiple TextView which set as marker in google location android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, onclicklistener

[image]

In above image I want to set onClickListener to multiple textViews

1. "Set this as delivery location", and
2. The star on the corner of "set this as delivery location"

I replaced the regular google marker with following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gps_location"
    android:id="@+id/g_location_box_image"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="@string/set_as_delivery_location"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/save_as_favorite"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/num_txt"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/num_txt"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`setOnClickListener` is not working with this as whole `RelativeLayout` is part of google maps now and not of activity.

I tried implementing `OnMarkerClickListener` but that makes all the `RelativeLayout` clickable. I need to listen two events as described above: 
one on "set this as delivery location" and other on the star resides next to it.

How can I achieve that ? Kindly help.

Following is the code used to replace the marker:

```
View marker = ((LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.google_marker, null);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(activity, marker)))
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to onclick on Marker you should use `InfoWindow` though you can't achieve multiple objects clickable. 
As per [Google Map Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows)

> An info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.